How to modify the size of an image via the 'StretchBlt' function?
When I run my codes, The image I want to display is much larger than the picture control - in fact, it takes up the entire dialog.
I wrote this :
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BaslerCode.h"
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"
#include "CImageEventHandler.h" 

void BaslerCode::OnImageGrabbed(CInstantCamera& camera, const CGrabResultPtr& ptrGrabResult)
{
     if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
    {
        CImage img;
        img.Create(imageRGB.GetWidth(), imageRGB.GetHeight(), 8); 

        imageRGB.GetWidth() * imageRGB.GetHeight());
        errno_t memcpy_s(void *dest,size_t destSize,const void *src,size_t count); 

        CWnd* pPictureBox = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();
        CDC* pDC = pPictureBox->GetDC();
        
        **img.StretchBlt(pDC->m_hDC,0,0,rect.Width(),rect.Height(),SRCCOPY);**

        img.Draw(pDC->m_hDC, 0, 0);
        pPictureBox->ReleaseDC(pDC);
    }
}


This is the documentation for the method of CImage: CImage::StretchBlt.

What is  control imageviewer? What is the current behavior of your code?

Your code does not contain the definition for rect (and others). But anyway - what is the actual problem that you have with your current code ? You should also post a [mre].

I've edited my post.

Isn't OnImageGrabbed called from the camera thread ? If so, you should not update the GUI from any thread apart from the main/UI thread. And BTW - rect is still not defined in the posted code.

I think the problem might be with this line:  CWnd* pPictureBox = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd(); - are you sure you're getting a pointer to your picture box and not your main window ?

You are using the wrong HWND.  What you need is imageviewer.
CWnd* pPictureBox = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();

and avoid redrawing. comment  //img.Draw(pDC->m_hDC, 0, 0);
Also  pay attention to  length and width  rect.Width(),rect.Height()

